# Draw a multi line chart of movie count by each genre for every year

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

As a part of my learning, I am using dataset of top movies data by IMDB data from 2006 to 2016 for EDA
Raw Data source: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/insaid2018/Term-1/master/Data/Projects/1000%20movies%20data.csv

I want to draw multi-line chart of movie counts by each genre for every year
A Sample is attached below:
[Sample photo of required chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vf6W4.png)

I created a Dataset in dataframe 'df' as below (first 5 rows only):
[sample photo of dataset showing first 5 rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQ6yN.png)
**Please help me to draw the desired multi-line chart from the dataframe 'df**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is necessary some preprocessing data before ploting by [`Series.str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
types = ['Action','Horror','Sci-Fi']
df1 = df.set_index('Year')['Genre'].str.get_dummies(',')[types].sum(level=0)

#multi-line chart
df1.plot()

#bar chart is better here I guess
df1.plot.bar()
```

Comment: @Manoj - I think best is create new question, with some sample data and expected output, [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)